# AutoIt3 - continue line in array

Tags: arrays, autoit

I got problem with array in AutoIt3. Max line lenght is 4095, so i need to continue array in next line:

```
Global $duza[1896] = ["p", "p", "p", "d", "p", "p", "p", "d", "p", "p", "p", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "s", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "s", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "s", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "s", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "s", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "s", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "s", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "s", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "s", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "s", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "s", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "s", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "s", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "s", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "s", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "s", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "s", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "s", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "s", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a","r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "s", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "s", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "s", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "s", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "s", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "s", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "s", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "s", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "s", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "s", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "a", "r", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can break long lines with an underscore like you would in VB like so:

```
Global $duza[1896] = [ _
"p", "p", "p", "d", "p", "p", "p", "d", "p", "p", _
"p", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", _
"d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", _
"d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", _
"d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", _
"d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", "d", "r", _
... ]
```

http://pastebin.com/Gw2LyazK